# C# ext change button's icon from code behind

Tags: c#, button, extjs, ext.net

I have this button:

```
<ext:Button Flat="true" runat="server" ID="btnCheckV" Icon="CheckError" Scale="Large" ToolTip="Is Valid" >
        <DirectEvents>
            <Click OnEvent="CheckValidity" />
        </DirectEvents>
</ext:Button>
```

And I want to change the icon of the button in code behind (tick for valid and cross for not valid). So I do it like this:

```
protected void CheckValidity(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
         //....validation check code
         if (isValid == true)
        {
            btnCheckV.Icon = Icon.Tick;
            e.Success = true;
        }
        else
        {
            btnCheckV.Icon = Icon.Cross;
            e.Success = false;
        }
    }
```

It works but only the first time I check. If for example the first time I check is valid it turns to tick, but if I check again and the data is invalid it won't change to cross

Comment: Is there a request from the browser after click? What is the value of `isValid` on second click? Does `btnCheckV`s `Icon` property receive `Icon.Cross` on second click? Does your browser get response from the server (if so what is the responseText)?

Comment: Please provide a simplified .aspx sample demonstrating the whole scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in this line:

```
e.Success = false;
```

If you set Success field to true in Direct Event, then your response looks like this:

```
{script:"btnCheckV.setIconCls(\"#Tick\");"}
```

When you set it to false, it looks like this:

```
{success:false}
```

As you can see, only the status of the Direct Event is send - nothing about icon in the button.

Change your code to:

```
protected void CheckValidity(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
{
    //....validation check code

    if (isValid == true)
        btnCheckV.Icon = Icon.Tick;
    else
        btnCheckV.Icon = Icon.Cross;

    e.Success = true;
}
```

And it will work without problem.